# Show all variations on the product detail page in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

Working with Shopware 6, I would like the product page to show all variations with prices on the storefront detail page like this image.

[image: Variations on the product detail page]

I have checked the `@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/configurator.html.twig` and `@Storefront/storefront/page/product-detail/buy-widget-form.html.twig` files and can see that the hidden inputs and select use the product.id

```
<select name="lineItems[{{ product.id }}][quantity]" ..>
```

to add these to the cart, but when I `dump(page.product)`, it only shows the default selected variant, one product.id, not all variant product ids. I am a little confused now as I am not sure how to proceed?

How can I list the variants with a select, listing all the product variant ids, if the page only shows one product variant id? And without the page refreshing when the variant changes. I thought there was a way to switch this off like in Shopware 5 but I am not able to see the setting for this in the backend of Shopware.

Comment: Maybe this article help you -> https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/add-data-to-a-storefront-page

Comment: Thanks @pedramshabani I have seen this article and have tried to create several simple subscribers to extend the product listing in the storefront. I am struggling a bit to fully understand the subscriber and how to really make it work for what I need, as I need a way to see the parent product id, and all the products associated with it, all the variants for that product. As I need a way for the LineItems to know which product needs to be added to cart, as I assume that all the selects have lineItems with different product ids.

Comment: I hope I understand your problem.If you check out address bar in browser, you'll  see when you select each variation relate to  product , URL changes.If you want to display all variations price in a details product you should use Twigfilter.Thus  get Id property that relate to each product and then search in product table , after that you can display  output  in  product details page

Comment: HI @pedramshabani sorry for the late response, I got a little sidetracked with another task. What do you mean by the Twigfilter? Do you mean using this in the subscriber? And how would I query it, as variants look to be their own product? Sorry a little confused by how to access what I need from the tables