# Find SEO URL of variant on product detail page

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am trying to lookup the seoUrl of variants displayed on a product detail page - in the configurator.html.twig file. I have the option Id and have tried passing it as productId for the seoUrl function - but it doesn't return the correct seoUrl.

Searching for a solution, I found this question: [Show all variations on the product detail page in Shopware 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594535/show-all-variations-on-the-product-detail-page-in-shopware-6) - which also lacks an answer.
But it hinted that you should add the data using a Subscriber - is that really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may decorate the `ProductDetailRoute`, fetch the parent and with its children association and iterate them in the storefront template.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Detail\ProductDetailRouteDecorator" public="true" decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Detail\ProductDetailRoute">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Detail\ProductDetailRouteDecorator.inner"/>
    <argument type="service" id="sales_channel.product.repository"/>
</service>
```

```php
class ProductDetailRouteDecorator extends AbstractProductDetailRoute
{
    private SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    private AbstractProductDetailRoute $decorated;

    public function __construct(
        AbstractProductDetailRoute $decorated,
        SalesChannelRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getDecorated(): AbstractProductDetailRoute
    {
        return $this->decorated;
    }

    public function load(string $productId, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context, Criteria $criteria): ProductDetailRouteResponse
    {
        $response = $this->getDecorated()->load($productId, $request, $context, $criteria);
        $product = $response->getProduct();

        if (!$product->getParentId()) {
            return $response;
        }

        $criteria = new Criteria([$product->getParentId()]);
        $criteria->addAssociation('children');

        $parent = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
        $product->setParent($parent);

        return new ProductDetailRouteResponse($product, $response->getConfigurator());
    }
}
```

```
{% if page.product.parent.children is defined %}
    {% for child in page.product.parent.children %}
        {{ seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { productId: child.id }) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endif %}
```

Sample output:

```
http://localhost/Intelligent-Marble-Ultra-Beef/0491895660e94e32938022263595f861
http://localhost/Intelligent-Marble-Ultra-Beef/7c9f91d9051e40e0ba13d0e885e98d83
http://localhost/Intelligent-Marble-Ultra-Beef/f25c641abee446df82e1227cf200186c
```

##### Variation on this solution

A little more complex but with a lesser performance impact:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', $product->getParentId()));

$ids = $this->productRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->getIds();
$product->addExtension('childrenIds', new ArrayStruct($ids));
```

```
{% if page.product.extensions.childrenIds is defined %}
    {% for childId in page.product.extensions.childrenIds.all() %}
        {{ seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { productId: childId }) }}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best solution would be to fetch all variants based on the parentId in a subscriber.

This is necessary because you want to have more data then just the productId. You should also consider this information as necessary:

1. minPurchase
2. calculatedMaxPurchase
3. purchaseSteps

And optional:

4. packUnit
5. packUnitPlural

Without the necessary product information the end user will possibly encounter errors when adding a product with a invalid quantity to the cart.

Comment: Okay - I'm nit sure I quite understand. I just want the seoUrl for the variant - and add it in the configuration.html.twig template - in the loop of variants.
So in order to do that I need to load all the variants for a product, fetch the seoUrls, and add them to an array and look it up in the template?

Sounds like quite some work :) but I'll give it a go